# Remove Text between two Strings

Tags: perl

I have a disclaimer message in an email which I want to remove using Perl.

The code is below:

```
my $stval = 'hii This is a test Email*************** CAUTION - Disclaimer *****************
        This e-mail contains PRIVILEGED AND CONFIDENTIAL INFORMATION intended solely
        for the use of the addressee(s). If you are not the intended recipient, please
        notify the sender by e-mail and delete the original message.
        ******MAILEND***** End of Disclaimer ******MAILEND*****';

$stval =~ s/[*]//g;    # this removes all * Characters
print "$stval\n\n";
```

The output I am expecting should be as below:

```
hii This is a test Email
```

Comment: And what it the Output you get?

Comment: That just removes asterisks.

Comment: try this  print $1 if($stval=~/([a-zA-Z \s]*)\*/);

Comment: As the comment says, `s/[*]//g` *“removes all \* characters”*. What did you want to do? No one can help unless you can describe precisely what part of the text you want to remove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That scalar string has several embedded \n, as if it is a here document.  You can remove everything from the first '*' to the end of the string with:

```
$stval =~ s/[*\n]+.+//g;    # this removes all * Characters
```

Comment: But can you suggest if i have to remove from 'CAUTION' text onward what can be the option. The reason why i am asking is if there is any * character in the mail then it will remove the text after that as well.

Comment: `my $stvalcopy = $stval;
print "$stval\n\n";
$stval =~ s/[*\n]+.+//g;    # this removes all * Characters
print "$stval\n\n";

print "$stvalcopy\n\n";
$stvalcopy =~ s/\s+Caution.*//is;    # this removes ' Caution' + all Characters
print "$stvalcopy\n\n";

print "Programming Perl (3rd) Chapter 5: Pattern Matching is must read/learn if you intend to stay with Perl\n";`

Answer (score -1):

Use `s` modifier to include newline in the deletion:

```
$stval =~ s/\*{10}.*//s;
```